# Whole button is not clickable on some of my pages

Tags: button

I have a site I created: http://www.raggeddaisy.com

On my Wooden Signs pages and Chalkboards pages, the 'Request More Information', only the top little bit of the button is clickable. The code is the same as my Magnetic Board and Wooden Benches pages. Why would this be?  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    <div id="requestInfoButton">
        <form action = "ContactUs.cshtml">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Request More Information">
        </form>
    </div>


#requestInfoButton {
    font  : 10pt 'Century Gothic';
    padding-top     :   2.25pt;
    position        : absolute;
    left            : 500.00pt;
    top             : 400.50pt;
    width           : 150pt;
    height          :  16.50pt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your div with id 'optionsWoodenSignLargePrice' is covering it. I wouldn't advice the styling you've used for just the text and especially the absolute  positioning.

[image]

However, removing the width and height attributes from the div#optionsWoodenSignLargePrice styles does solve your problem.

Comment: If I have answered your question sufficiently you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two divs that are absolutely positioned with a fixed width that cover the majority of that request more info button. If you remove the width on div#optionsWoodenSignSmallPrice and div#optionsWoodenSignLargePrice your button will be clickable.